# Tell getopt it's not done parsing option

Tags: c, getopt

I'm using getopt to parse options. One of the options I parse (`-a`) has a mandatory argument.

My getopt call looks like this:

```
while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "a:b")) != -1) {
    switch(c) {
    case 'a':
        foo = atoi(optarg);
        break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Here's my problem:

Suppose someone runs `./my-command -a100b`. I want my program to tell that there is a `-a` option with an argument 100 *and* a `-b` option. However, getopt parses this as a `-a` option with an argument `100b`.

How can I tell getopt that it's not done parsing `-a100b`? I want to tell getopt to start parsing at the character `b`, so that it recognizes that there is a `-b` option.

Comment: No, there's no way to do that. It's just not the kind of option syntax it's designed to support. `getopt` parsing is consistent with POSIX standard options, and that's not consistent with the standard.

Comment: How should it know that the argument ends after `100` and doesn't include the `b`?

Comment: ... and why are you using `atoi`?

Comment: @Barmar `getopt` wouldn't know, but the code processing `-a` would know that it only accepts integers, and that the first non-digit character was part of the next option.

Comment: `getopt` can only parse whole arguments. There's no way to tell it to go back and treat the `b` at the end as the next option, since it doesn't begin with `-`.

Comment: @EdHeal The mandatory argument to `-a` is always an integer. I have a `char*`, I want an integer, therefore, `atoi`.

Comment: Like I said, this is just not the kind of argument syntax that `getopt` was designed to recognize. If you have ideosyncratic requirements, you need to write your own parser.

Comment: @Barmar It's important for backwards compatibility that it be able to parse options like this. I recognize that it's non-standard, but arguing with all of the people who use this utility is much harder than writing code that can accept weird input.

Comment: @NickODell - But a person might not type in an integer

Comment: Backwards compatibility with what? If there's already an implementation that uses this syntax, why can't you use its parser, instead of trying to shoehorn it into `getopt`?

Comment: You should probably use `strtol()` instead of `atoi`, which will parse the initial integer and tell you where it ends. Then you can check the remainder for options.

Comment: @EdHeal A valid point. I'll change it to `strtol`.

Comment: @Barmar I'd prefer that it use something standard. The current option-parsing code is hard to read.

Comment: @Barmar `Then you can check the remainder for options.` Yes, I'd like to do that. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: I thought you wanted `getopt` to do that for you, instead of doing it yourself.

Comment: If your argument format were `a:b:`, would you expect to be able to write `-a100b50` and have this parsed as if it were `-a 100 -b 50`?

Comment: You can't have it both ways. If you use `getopt`, you're limited to standard option syntax. If you want non-standard option syntax, you have to use a custom parser.

Comment: `getopt` is open source, you could take the code and make your own version that has a way to back up and start from the middle of an argument.

Comment: @Barmar `I thought you wanted` Here's what I'd like: I have a pointer to where I'd like getopt to continue parsing. I want the next call to getopt to continue parsing there.  `If your argument format were` Sure, that would be great.

Comment: But if you tell it to continue parsing at the `b`, there won't be a `-` before it, so it will treat it as the first non-option argument. So you also want it to pretend that there's a `-` where it continues.

Comment: The answer to your question is very simple: How can I tell it this? You can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suppose someone runs `./my-command -a100b`. I want my program to tell
>   that there is a `-a` option with an argument 100 *and* a `-b` option.
>   However, getopt parses this as a `-a` option with an argument `100b`.

Yes, it does.  That's how the option language parsed by `getopt()` works.

> How can I tell getopt that it's not done parsing `-a100b`? I want to
>   tell getopt to start parsing at the character `b`, so that it recognizes
>   that there is a `-b` option.

You can't.  Neither POSIX-standard `getopt()` nor any extended version I am aware of (e.g. GNU's) supports such a thing.  In particular, the [POSIX specficiation for `getopt`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) says, in part,

> The `getopt()` function is a command-line parser that shall follow
>   Utility Syntax Guidelines 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, and 10 in XBD Utility
>   Syntax Guidelines.

[Those guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) are about command-line options and how they are formatted.  The ones most relevant to your question are:

> **Guideline 3:**
>       Each option name should be a single alphanumeric character (the alnum character classification) from the portable character set. [...]
>
> **Guideline 4:**
>       All options should be preceded by the '-' delimiter character.
>
> **Guideline 5:**
>       One or more options without option-arguments, followed by at most one option that takes an option-argument, should be accepted when
>   grouped behind one '-' delimiter.
>
> **Guideline 6:**
>       Each option and option-argument should be a separate argument, except as noted in Utility Argument Syntax, item (2).

Note especially guideline 5: when you group options together, only the last may be one that takes an argument.  This allows the tail of that group or the next full argument to be interpreted as the argument, which is what you see `getopt` doing.

Of course, if you want your program to accept options that do not conform to POSIX guidelines then you are free to do make it do so, but you'll probably need to perform your own option parsing.  Maybe you can get `getopt` to help, but you would need to add a non-trivial custom parsing layer on top.  It might be easier to just roll your own from scratch.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. I appreciate the reference to a specific part of the guidelines and the actionable advice.

Comment: Another way of looking at this is that `getopt()` treats option arguments as strings; it has no concept of a numeric option argument, so it cannot possibly recognize `100b` as anything other than a string of 4 characters that is the option argument for the `-a` option.  This applies whether the command line contains `-a100b` or `-a 100b`.  It isn't clear what the OP would want to happen with `-a 100b` as two arguments — but `getopt()` treats that as conveying the same information as `-a100b`.